# Python len() not returning whole numbers

Tags: python, struct, types

I am currently working modifying some code I found on Github. It is for a spectrum analyzer using ath9k-based wireless cards.

Anyways, the issue is with this bit of code here:

```
sdata = struct.unpack_from("56B", data, pos)
pos += 56

# calculate power in dBm
sumsq_sample = 0
samples = []
for raw_sample in sdata:
    if raw_sample == 0:
        sample = 1
    else:
        sample = raw_sample << max_exp
    sumsq_sample += sample*sample
    samples.append(sample)

print (len(samples))
```

I expect the last print statement to always produce the value "56", however I have run into some strange behavior. Here is some example output:

```
56
56
56
56
56
56
56S 15.952354 
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56S 15.689883 
56
56S 16.510071 
56
56S 17.591084 
56S 18.358299 
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
56
```

This makes no sense to me. I have checked the documentation for len() and struct.unpack_from(), but haven't gotten anywhere. Samples should contain 56 one-byte integers but occasionally I get odd values like "56S 10.237633"

Github repo of project I am modifying can be found at https://github.com/bcopeland/speccy
Code sample above is from spectrum_file.py starting at line 87

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal example?

Comment: Is the script single threaded?
Also, is the indentation correct?

Comment: @JonasAdler No, I cannot reduce it to a minimal example. The strange "56S 12.322341" style output occurs randomly.

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie No, it is multithreaded. However the other threads only handle starting and stopping the scanner. No other print statements could be producing this output. The indentation is correct. len() should only be called once each time the above code is executed.

Comment: `len` is working correctly - every line starts with `56`. My bet is that other thread is printing to `stdout` or `stderr`. If you add newline character to the end of `len` print, these "strange" lines (e.g. `S 18.358299`) will be on separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @kchomski, your issue is due to another part of your program writing to `stderr`.

I found the following line of code in `speccy.py`, which I believe is causing the unexpected output:

```
sys.stderr.write('FPS %f \r' % (sum(self.fps) / len(self.fps)))
```

An [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be the following:

```
import sys

sys.stderr.write('TOSTDERR\r')
print('54')
```

which outputs:

```
54STDERR
```

The carriage return character `\r` is moving your cursor back to the beginning of the line and then the `54` is printed on top of what was previously written to `stderr`.

You can resolve the issue by switching `\r` to `\n` which will put a new line at the end of the output to `stderr` and avoid this issue of overwriting.